# Proving without using the given condition

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:\;\mathbb R\longmapsto\;\mathbb R$, $A,B\subset\mathbb R$. Suppose we have $f(A)\subseteq B$, then prove

(1) $f^{-1}(\overline{A})=\overline{f^{-1}(A)}$;

(2) $f^{-1}(A \cup B)=f^{-1}(A) \cup f^{-1}(B)$;

(3) $f^{-1}(A \cap B)=f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$.

By [357725](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357725/show-that-f-1a-cup-b-f-1a-cup-f-1b) , [291777](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291777/f-1-s-cup-t-f-1-s-cup-f-1-tb) and [228711](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228711/what-are-the-strategies-i-can-use-to-prove-f-1s-cap-t-f-1s-cap-f?noredirect=1&lq=1) ,  one can  prove the above 3 formulas as follows

(1)
$$
\begin{aligned}
f^{-1}(\overline{A}) &:=\{x \in \operatorname{dom}(f): f(x) \in \overline A \} \\
&=\{x \in \operatorname{dom}(f): f(x) \notin A \} \\
&=: \overline{f^{-1}(A)}.
\end{aligned}
$$
(2)
$$
\begin{aligned}
f^{-1}(A \cup B) &:=\{x \in \operatorname{dom}(f): f(x) \in A \cup B\} \\
&=\{x \in \operatorname{dom}(f): f(x) \in A \text { or } f(x) \in B\} \\
&=\{x \in \operatorname{dom}(f): f(x) \in A\} \cup\{x \in \operatorname{dom}(f): f(x) \in B\} \\
&=: f^{-1}(A) \cup f^{-1}(B) .
\end{aligned}
$$
(3)
$$
\begin{aligned}
f^{-1}(A \cap B) &:=\{x \in \operatorname{dom}(f): f(x) \in A \cap B\} \\
&=\{x \in \operatorname{dom}(f): f(x) \in A \text { and } f(x) \in B\} \\
&=\{x \in \operatorname{dom}(f): f(x) \in A\} \cap\{x \in \operatorname{dom}(f): f(x) \in B\} \\
&=: f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B).
\end{aligned}
$$
It seems that I prove the processes without using the condition *Suppose we have $f(A)\subseteq B$*.

Is this condition unnecessary?  Or am I missing something?  A counterexample?

Comment: Just looking at the proofs, yes, I don't think $f(A)\subseteq B$ is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, $f(A) \subseteq B$ is unnecessary for the exercises as they are currently presented.

Consider the following set of exercises:

(a) $A \subseteq B \implies f^{-1}(A) \subseteq f^{-1}(B)$

(b) $f^{-1}(A \cup B) = f^{-1}(A) \cup f^{-1}(B)$;

(c) $f^{-1}(A \cap B) = f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$.

Such a set of exercises may be found in the beginning chapter of *Topology* by Munkres, and indeed — there is no requirement that $f(A) \subseteq B$. Your proofs are definitely valid. The only requirement is that $A,B$ are subsets of the range of $f$, which you said they are.

The point of the exercises is to prove that the preimage of a function preserves inclusions, unions, intersections, and set differences.

Comment: It's really kind of you ! I will ref the beginning chapter of *Topology by Munkres*@polite proofs